# WordPress API for search

Tags: users, search, rest-api, wp-api

I have a search form for users on my website. I have a custom field called 'location' which is a country dropdown. If I type in a user's name and select a country from the dropdown I see this in the url when I submit:

```
https://example.com/?s=bob&location=germany
```

If I search for bob in France I get no results because bob has set his location to Germany.
If I just search for bob I will find him.
if I just search in Germany I will find him.
If I search for Bob in Germany I will find him.

So, I want the same thing using the API.

If I send a GET request to

```
 https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users?search=bob
```

I get a result as I would want. But if I try just by location or name and location, I just get ALL the users back.

So, I tried:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users?location=germany
```

This gave me all the users and this also gave me all the users

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users?search=bob&location=germany
```

Search

```
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'name', 'placeholder', 'ae' ); ?>" value="<?php get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />
                <?php
        $location_key = "field_5eddd6b77adb0";
        $field = get_field_object($location_key);
        if ( $field ): ?>
            <select id="location" name="location">
                <option value="">Select Country</option>
                <?php foreach ( $field['choices'] as $k => $v ): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $k; ?>"><?php echo $v; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?> 
            </select>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Then on the search results page:

```
$s_query        = $_GET['s'];
$country        = $_GET['location'];
$meta_query = [];
        if ( $country ) {
            $meta_query[] = [ // top-level clause
                'key'     => 'location',
                'value'   => $country,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ];
        }
$args = [
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'number'     => $users_per_page,
    'paged' => $current_page,

];

$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

Comment: How are you filtering front end results by the custom field? It’s not default behaviour, unless it’s a taxonomy or you’ve added code.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thanks for your response. I have updated my question to show some code. It is an advanced custom field.

Comment: You're much better off here if you were using a custom taxonomy for countries, another one for username, and then wp_query your posts by defining that the according post must have the provided country & username tag. Anyway, if you insist on using meta queries; you need to specify the "relation" => "AND" key - value pair in your query arguments; to make sure your results contain both.